# I have this form in a dialog box, but i cannot get the values of the input boxes

Tags: android, dialog

I have a dialog box with a form, the user enters some data and i want to get that data but when i log the data to view it i am getting nothing.

```
  public Dialog onCreateDialog (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.incident_form,null);


        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.incident_form,null)
                .setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {
                        title = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.report_title);
                        recom = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.report_recommendation);
                        content = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.report_content);

                        titleString = title.getText().toString();
                        recomString = recom.getText().toString();
                        contentString = content.getText().toString();

                        submitForm(titleString,recomString,contentString);
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
```

Comment: remove setNegativeButton and setPositivetiveButton when you are using custom layout for it.

Comment: why you are including your layout twice ?

Comment: @PreetikaKaur thanks for pointing that out, i didn't notice it. solved the problem

Comment: can i comment it as answer and if it helps then accept my answer @lagfvu

Comment: @PreetikaKaur sure

Comment: @lagfvu done kindly accept and upvote it.. Thanku...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have included the layout twice in you dialog please check.
Either **setview(View)** you should use because view you have already initialized on the top like this

> ```
>     final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.incident_form,null);
> ```

or intialize it in you **setView()** method like you are doing below

> setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.incident_form,null)

. You are adding it twice that is why this is happening.

Glad to help you...

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code like this:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.incident_form,null);
                        title = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.report_title);
                        recom = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.report_recommendation);
                        content = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.report_content);


        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.incident_form,null)
                .setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {

                        titleString = title.getText().toString();
                        recomString = recom.getText().toString();
                        contentString = content.getText().toString();

                        submitForm(titleString,recomString,contentString);
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate your `EditText` like this:

```
EditText storyNameTxt = (EditText) getDialog().findViewById(R.id.dialog_add_story_name);
```

`getDialog` do the trick for for me.